# Modelica propagation/default variable name

Tags: modelica

I want to set a default variable name T (=xx) inside a model - drag that model into a new model and define there the variable xx.
I get the error message: Use of undeclared variable xx.

This is the sub-model

```
model test
  parameter Real T = xx;
  Real f;
equation 
  f = T + time;
end test;
```

this is the full model

```
model fullmodel
  parameter Real xx = 12;
  Test Test1; 
end fullmodel;
```

My question: How would you do that in Modelica? I need for my model 100 of the same models and i want to set a few parameters (diamter, lenghts, etc.) per default to a variable name and then define just this variables. I know i could propagate the variable - but it would be nice, if i just have to drag the model and then defining the parameters. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can do this using inner/outer:

```
model Test
  outer parameter Real xx;
  parameter Real T = xx;
  Real f;
equation 
  f = T + time;
end Test;

model fullmodel
  inner parameter Real xx = 12;
  Test test1;
end fullmodel;
```

Comment: This way you don't need to change anything inside Test or add a modifier when you use it inside fullmodel,

Comment: I avoid `inner` and `outer` keywords if at all possible.  Yes, you might feel like having to propagate information into the hierarchy is tedious when you have multiple components.  But in my experience, this approach based on `inner` and `outer` will quickly degenerate.  The issue is that relationships in the hierarchy are implicit rather than explicit.  Your models will quickly degenerate into a brittle, monolithic mess.  About the only legitimate use case for something like this involve fundamental assumptions that you need to cascade to all components.

Comment: Yes, inner/outer might be good to be avoided. I guess if you have 100 models to drag and drop it might be better to actually generate that big model automatically using some scripting language, and then you could include the modifiers automatically.

Comment: If you have a 100 models, you probably need an array.  With an array of components only a single modification is required (*e.g.,* `each T=xx`).  I have another solution if you have lots of instances of the same class, but I don't want to post it in a comment so I'll create another solution.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do something like:

```
model test
  parameter Real T;
  Real f;
equation 
  f = T + time;
end test;

model fullmodel
  parameter Real xx = 12;
  Test Test1(T = xx);
end fullmodel;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply: If i do it that way and I drag for example 100 "test"model in "fullmodel", then I have to define in every "test" (T=xx) right?

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility if you have multiple instances of the same model and you don't want to repeat the modification is to do something like this:

```
model test
  parameter Real T;
  parameter Real S=1;
  Real f;
equation 
  f = S*(T + time);
end test;

model fullmodel
  parameter Real xx = 12;
  // Create an "alias" model using a short class definition that
  // includes a modification (for all instances of PreConfig).
  model PreConfig = Test1(T=xx);
  // Now create instances (potentially with their own unique values
  // for some parameters
  PreConfig pc1(S=1), pc2(S=2), pc3(S=3);
end fullmodel;
```

As I mentioned in the comment above, another implementation of `fullmodel` that uses an array would look like this:

```
model fullmodel
  parameter Integer n = 100;
  parameter Real xx = 12;
  // Create 100 instances of Test1.  Each on has the same
  // value for T, but they each have different values for
  // S
  Test1 tarray[n](each T=xx, S=linspace(0, 1, n));
end fullmodel;
```